# Sahi - open window to select file to upload

Tags: file-upload, automated-tests, popupwindow, sahi

I am trying to upload a file using Sahi. It is the usual upload file step, click on the 'Upload File', then popup window opens for user to select the file, then click open.

Sahi doesn't recognise the popup window.  I tried to use the `_setFile`, doesn't seem to do anything.  Could any one please help?

```
_setFile(_file("uploadForm:j_id_1d_input"), "\\scripts\\II\\image\\png.png");
```

Many thanks

Comment: Please read everything here: "http://sahi.co.in/docs/sahi-apis/action-apis.html#File Upload" (regard the quotes!) maybe you don't have to escape backslashes? Maybe you try native uploading?

Answer (score 0):

You are using invalid path , 
below URL path can help you.....

```
_setFile2(_file("modelFile"), "C:\\users\\sfatimi\\Desktop\\excel-model-4.1.jar")
```

You can use both  , `_setfile2` and `_setfile`

if you some validations implemented on uploading use `_setfile2`